# problemas para crear un boton de eliminar items en react

Tags: array, reactjs, objeto, id, tailwind

estoy creando un formulario para generar un presupuesto con react, esto teniendo problemas para configurar el boton de borrar que pretendo que lleve cada item durante la creación del presupuesto (los items son objetos dentro de un array)

1.-he intentado usar el **id** que lleva cada item pero no he logrado acceder al **id**.

2.-he pensado en hacer la eliminación a traves del indice que ocupa cada objeto dentro del array que los contiene pero no he logrado dar con la solucion.

dejo el codigo completo para que puedan tener una mejor vision de la situacion.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Budget = ({ cambiazo }) => {

  let date = new Date();
  let output = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  let count = 0
  let sum = 0;
  const ini = 0;
  let calcIva;
  let calcTotal;

  const { client, cel, mail, reception, promise, possibleFailure, km, failure, delivered, brand, model, id, year, now } = cambiazo

  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [description, setDescripcion] = useState("");
  const [cant, setCant] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [prod, setProd] = useState('');
  const [pine, setPine] = useState([]);
  const [subTotal, setSubTotal] = useState(0);
  const [iva, setIva] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [discount, setDiscount] = useState('');
  const [tButton, setTButton] = useState('Generar');
  const [cButton, setCButton] = useState('red');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const generateId = () => {
    const dateNow = Date.now().toString(36).toUpperCase();
    return dateNow;
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (description, cant, price) {
      const objDetail = {
        id: generateId(),
        description,
        cant,
        price,
        prod: cant * price,
      }      

      count = cant * price
      setPine([...pine, count])

      setDetails([...details, objDetail])

      setDescripcion('');
      setCant('');
      setPrice('');

    }

  }
        
  const fCalcTotal = () => {
    
    sum = pine.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, ini);
    setSubTotal(sum)

    calcIva = sum * 0.21;
    setIva(calcIva)

    calcTotal = ((sum + iva)-discount);
    setTotal(calcTotal)

    if(tButton === 'Sub-Total'){
      setTButton('Total')
      setCButton('green')
      setDisabled(true)

    }else{
      setTButton('Sub-Total')
      setCButton('yellow')
      setDisabled(false)
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full border bg-red-200  text-xs sm:text-base md:text-lg'>

      <p className='bg-blue-200 text-center text-2xl my-4 p-2'>Presupuesto</p>

      <div className='w-full h-auto flex'>
        <div className='w-1/2 border-gray-600 border-2 p-2 mx-2'>
          <p>Cliente</p>
          <p>Telefono</p>
          <p>Email</p>
        </div>

        <div className='w-1/2 border-2 border-gray-600 p-2 mx-2'>
          <p>{client}</p>
          <p>{cel}</p>
          <p>{mail}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='flex mt-2 border-2 border-gray-600 mx-2'>
        <p className='w-1/2 p-2 mx-2'>{`Fecha del presupuesto: ${output}`}</p>
        <p className='w-1/2 p-2 mx-2'>Validez: 10 días habiles</p>
      </div>

      <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className=' border-2 border-gray-600 p-2 mx-2 mt-2 flex flex-col'>

        <div className='w-full flex justify-between'>
          <p className='w-2/3'>Descripción</p>
          <p className='text-center w-1/4'>Cant.</p>
          <p className='text-center w-1/4'>Precio</p>
        </div>

        <div className='w-full flex justify-between items-center py-1'>
          <input type="text" id="description" className='mr-1 w-2/3 h-5' value={description} onChange={(e) => setDescripcion(e.target.value)} />
          <input type="number" id="cant" className='mx-1 w-1/6 h-5' value={cant} onChange={(e) => setCant(e.target.value)} />
          <input type="number" id="price" className='mx-1 w-1/6 h-5' value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
          <button type='submit' className='bg-blue-400  rounded-full w-6 h-5 text-lg text-white flex items-center justify-center'>+</button>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="discount">Descuento</label>
          <input type="number" id="discount" className='mx-1 w-12 h-5' value={discount} onChange={(e) => setDiscount(e.target.value)} />
        </div>

        <div className='flex justify-center'>
          <button className='border w-1/2 m-3 p-1.5 rounded-lg shadow-lg' style={{backgroundColor:`${cButton}`}} onClick={() => fCalcTotal() && changeButton()} disabled={disabled}>{tButton}</button>
        </div>
      </form>

      <div className=' border-2 border-gray-600 p-2 mx-2 mt-2 flex flex-col'>
        {details.map((d) => (
          <div className='w-full flex justify-between items-center py-1' key={d.id}>

            <p className='mr-1 bg-white w-2/3 h-5 flex items-center'>{d.description}</p>
            <p className='mx-1 bg-white w-1/6 h-5 flex justify-center items-center'>{d.cant}</p>
            <p className='mx-1 bg-white w-1/6 h-5 flex justify-center items-center'>{d.price}</p>
            <p className='mx-1 bg-white w-1/6 h-5 flex items-center justify-center'>{d.prod}</p>
            <button className='w-6 h-5 rounded-full flex justify-center items-center text-white text-xs bg-red-600 border-slate-900' onClick={() => console.log(details)}>x</button>


          </div>
        ))}

      </div>

      <div className="mt-2 border-2 border-gray-600 mx-2">
        <div className='flex justify-end px-2'>
          <p className='mx-7'>Sub-Total</p>
          <p>{`${subTotal.toFixed(2)}€`}</p>
        </div>

        <div className='flex justify-end px-2'>
          <p className='mx-7'>Descuento</p>
          <p>{`${discount}€`}</p>
        </div>

        <div className='flex justify-end px-2'>
          <p className='mx-7'>Iva(21%)</p>
          <p>{`${iva.toFixed(2)}€`}</p>
        </div>

        <div className='flex justify-end px-2'>
          <p className='mx-7'>Total Presupuesto</p>
          <p>{`${total.toFixed(2)}€`}</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div className="mt-2 border-2 border-gray-600 mx-2 flex">
        <div className='w-2/3 h-[100px] flex justify-center items-center border '>
          <p>Firma y Sello</p>
        </div>

        <div className='w-1/3 h-[100px] flex justify-center items-center border-l-2 border-gray-600'>
          <p>Firma del Cliente</p>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  )
}

export default Budget
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu código es muy largo, señala la parte en que estás tratando de hacer eso, que hace actualmente esa parte, y si puede poner un ejemplo.

Comment: No veo cuál es la función para eliminar, asumo que el problema esta en el botón con la x dentro del map de details. siendo así, ese console.log que tienes va a imprimir el arreglo entero, ya estas iterando el arreglo con un map por lo que si quieres el id solo necesitas console.log(d.id) de esa manera va a imprimir el id y si lo que quieres es enviarlo a tu función pues sería algo como: onClick={() => tuFuncionBorrar(d.id) donde tuFunctionBorrar recibe el parametro id

Comment: Gracias Sres. por su ayuda. Alex Varela me diste la clave para encontrar el camino.